# Lookup Username for SID in Azure Rest API C#

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I have a SID (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1531374245-1204410969-2402986413-2179508616-0-0-0-0-1) and I have the ACLs for it using the Azure DevOps Security Rest API.  What I am trying to do is lookup the user (username or email) associated with that and I can't seem to find the right API call.  Anyone ever tried to do this?  PS the SID above is bogus but I included it as an example of what I am trying to lookup.

I have tried using the graph api to lookup a user and go the other direction as well.  But I haven't been able to find a way to create a SID for a user in that direction.  If I could then I would be able to brute force search for the SID in the descriptors of the access control lists. Not really what I want to do but if it is the only way I will take it.

If it would help I can describe what it is I am trying to do:

- We have 70+ Team Projects that we manage
- We need to grant access to the QA managers team to work with shared queries on the Board.
- We do this manually by Clicking on Board > Queries > Shared Queries > … > Security
- We then add the groups and then Allow the Contributor permission for that group
- We want to programmatically do this set of steps using the Azure DevOps Rest API
- I need to translate between a Graph User and the SID listed in the ACE entries on an ACL in the SecurityNamespace for the Query permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kevin's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411920/get-a-list-of-who-has-what-access-to-git-repositories) contains more details about the identities call.

There is an identities api you can call to translate.  You send the whole descriptor, or a list of descriptors, and it will give back the entries.  Contained is the Display name for the principal.

There must be a better way to get the raw data, but here is an example powershell...

```
 $namespaces = Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -Headers $securityHeader -Uri 'https://dev.azure.com/<Your Account>/_apis/securitynamespaces/?api-version=5.1'
 $projectsGuid = <The GUID for Project from the $namespaces>
 $projectACLs = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $securityHeader -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/<Your Account>/_apis/accesscontrollists/$projectsGuid/?api-version=5.1&recurse=true"

 $projectACLs.value | % {
     $project = $_
     $props = Get-Member -InputObject $project.acesDictionary -MemberType NoteProperty
     $props | % {
         Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $securityHeader -Uri "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/<Your Account>/_apis/identities?descriptors=$($_.Name)"
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you I searched and searched for the identities API and didn't come across it.  Thank you.