# Azure DevOps Permissions Report - going beyond the default count of 100

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use the Azure DevOps [Permissions Report - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/permissionsreport/permissions%20report/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) REST API to download a list of permission reports that were generated by me. The subsequent operation is to download each report. The issue I am facing is 'List' provides only 100 reports at once. I can't seem to get more than 100 reports by supplying parameters like $top, $skip as suggested in a few discussions. There is no x-ms-continuation-token either. As I am using this approach to generate permissions report for Azure Repos, the number of reports are really large, well beyond 100.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this REST API [Permissions Report - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/permissionsreport/permissions%20report/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) has not yet been fully implemented:
[image]

And there is no x-ms-continuation-token parameter and so on as you have found. See [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450768/how-to-list-the-groups-user-who-has-permissions-to-the-project-repo-with-azure-d) for more details.

BTW, you could submit your feedback [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues), so the author could review it.