# How to list the user who has permissions to the Azure DevOps project repo with powershell/ Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I want to get the list of users who has access of Azure DevOps Repo using PowerShell script or azure CLI.

Comment: Have you gone through SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/63453972/15968720, Does this Helpful for you ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

[**az devops user list**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/devops/user?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_devops_user_list&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5001515)  = use this command to list all users on Azure DevOps organization.

```
az devops user list   
[--detect {false, true}]                       
[--org]                       
[--skip]                       
[--top]$allUsers = az devops user list --org $Organization | ConvertFrom-Jsonforeach($au in $allUsers.members)  
{  
    Write-Host $au.user.principalName  
}
```

We have the **Azure Pipelines PowerShell Module** to create a report of listing the users/groups having permissions to the repositories as given detailed in this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63453972/16630138) .

**References:**

- https://vinijmoura.medium.com/how-to-list-all-users-and-group-permissions-on-azure-devops-using-azure-devops-cli-54f73a20a4c7