# How to list permissions in source control for Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2020

I need to review all source code permissions on a particular folder structure. I have gone through the apis and can't find what I need or haven't figured out how to use them correctly yet.
I have also tried the tfssecurity command but, can't figure out how to make it look at just a specific team project.

I am using Azure DevOps Server 2020 and the source is in TFVC.

This is part of a source control audit and I need to produce a report of what permissions users have on a folder in source.

I have tried the following apis: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0
Along with the tfssecurity command.

None are producing the results I need.

Comment: From Azure DevOps Server 2020, there should be a same repo security permission view (the same as Service) in Project Settings -> Repo -> choose your target TFVC repo -> Security -> Download Detailed report.

Comment: Unfortunately that option is not available in onprem. I have even checked 2022, and it's not there either.

Comment: I have checked the TFS 2020 view, there's no "Download Detailed report". Similar to your scenario, the API for this seems not implemented: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450768/how-to-list-the-groups-user-who-has-permissions-to-the-project-repo-with-azure-d

Answer (score 0):

Found the APIs needed to do this.

Use this one to get all of the namespaces and find the ones that you want to get the security data for.
https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/securitynamespaces

After that call this API to get the ACLs for that namespace.
https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/accesscontrollists/{securityNamespaceId}?alwaysAllowAdministrators=True

Once you get all of the ACLs for the namespace, you can then look at each ACE to  find out the permissions.
https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/identities?descriptors={descriptors}&queryMembership=expandedDown